# FullScreen Mode in flex mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

i have a video stage need to add a full screen button , i added this code :

```
private function makeFullScreenVideo(e:Event):void
    {
        saveOldestPositionAndSizeOfVideo();
        if(!isFull)
        {
            stage.getChildAt(0).x = 0;
            stage.getChildAt(0).y = 0;
            stage.getChildAt(0).width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
            stage.getChildAt(0).height = stage.fullScreenHeight; 

        }
        else
        {
            if(stage.fullScreenHeight>stage.fullScreenWidth)
            {
                stage.getChildAt(0).x = oldXOfVerticalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).y = oldYOfVerticalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).width = oldWidthOfVerticalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).height = oldHeightOfVerticalView;   
            }
            else
            {
                stage.getChildAt(0).x = oldXOfHorizentalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).y = oldYOfHorizentalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).width = oldWidthOfHorizentalView;
                stage.getChildAt(0).height = oldHeightOfHorizentalView;
            } 
        }

        isFull = !isFull;

    }
    private function saveOldestPositionAndSizeOfVideo():void
    {
        if(stage.fullScreenHeight>stage.fullScreenWidth)
        {
            oldWidthOfVerticalView = stage.fullScreenWidth;
            oldHeightOfVerticalView= stage.fullScreenHeight*0.468;
            oldXOfVerticalView= 0;
            oldYOfVerticalView= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(oldWidthOfHorizentalView == 0)
            {
                oldWidthOfHorizentalView = stage.getChildAt(0).width;
                oldHeightOfHorizentalView= stage.getChildAt(0).height;
                oldXOfHorizentalView= stage.getChildAt(0).x;
                oldYOfHorizentalView= stage.getChildAt(0).y;    
            }
        }
    }
```

this code work good when i run it .
the problem is when the orientation is changed , if change the orientation of full screen mode it will not do for code i write it inside `StageOrientationEvent` :

```
private function changeOrientation(evt:StageOrientationEvent):void
    {
        if(isFull)
        {
            stage.getChildAt(0).x = 0;
            stage.getChildAt(0).y = 0;
            stage.getChildAt(0).width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
            stage.getChildAt(0).height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
        }
    }
```

Hint : if i run the project on Desktop not on Devise it will work excellent and there is no problem on orientation .

Comment: Hi Sameer I've also run into issues with the StageOrientationEvent in a mobile project, somewhat similar issue except it just doesn't fire when returning to the default orientation.  I ended up just relying on the Accelerometer class to determine the orientation myself if you'd like I can post that code.

Comment: @shaunhusain : yes i'd like that , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code I put together for my own project after I was having some difficulties with the built in StageOrientationEvents.  Please note this is a WIP so if you have any suggestions please let me know.  There's two classes I made one Singleton and one Event it dispatches, to use it I get the instance of the singleton and add listeners for the events:

[AccelerometerManager.as]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.managers
{
    import com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.events.AccBasedOrientationEvent;

    import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;

    /**
     * Centralizes the handling of accelerometer changes, limits events
     * dispatched to avoid extraneous jiggle/dithering.
     */
    public class AccelerometerManager extends EventDispatcher
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Constants
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static const LANDSCAPE_LEFT:String = "landscapeLeft";
        public static const LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:String = "landscapeRight";
        public static const PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:String = "portraitDefault";
        public static const PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:String = "portraitFlipped";

        public static const TURNED_RIGHT:String = "turnedRight";
        public static const TURNED_LEFT:String = "turnedLeft";
        public static const FLIPPED:String = "flipped";

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Variables
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private var acc:Accelerometer;
        private var registeredStageListener:Boolean;
        private var previousOrientation:String=PORTRAIT_DEFAULT;
        private var degreeAllowance:Number = 20;
        private var previousAngle:Number=270;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Constructor
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Used to coordinate all the updates to the buttons without having
         * multiple instances of accelerometer objects.  Creates the handle
         * to the Accelerometer.
         * 
         * @param se Blocks creation of new managers instead use static method getInstance
         */
        public function AccelerometerManager(se:SingletonEnforcer)
        {
            acc = new Accelerometer();
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Singleton
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static var instance:AccelerometerManager;
        public static function getIntance():AccelerometerManager
        {
            if( instance == null ) instance = new AccelerometerManager( new SingletonEnforcer() );
            return instance;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Properties
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private var _currentlyActive:Boolean;
        /**
         * Allows the manager to be turned on or off from the outside.
         */
        public function set currentlyActive(value:Boolean):void{
            if(_currentlyActive == value)
                return;
            _currentlyActive = value;
            if(_currentlyActive)
                acc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, handleAccelerometerChange);
            else
                acc.removeEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, handleAccelerometerChange);
        }

        private var _currentOrientation:String = AccelerometerManager.PORTRAIT_DEFAULT;
        public function get currentOrientation():String
        {
            return _currentOrientation;
        }

        public function set currentOrientation(value:String):void
        {
            _currentOrientation = value;
        }


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Handlers
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
        private function handleAccelerometerChange(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
        {
            if(Math.abs(event.accelerationZ)<.75)
            {
                var angle:Number = Math.atan2(event.accelerationY, event.accelerationX);
                var degrees:Number = angle*180/Math.PI+180;

                if(Math.abs(degrees - previousAngle)<degreeAllowance)
                    return;

                previousAngle = degrees;

                var accEventExtra:AccBasedOrientationEvent = new AccBasedOrientationEvent(event.type,event.bubbles,event.cancelable);
                if(degrees>225&&degrees<315)
                    currentOrientation = PORTRAIT_DEFAULT;
                else if(degrees>45&&degrees<135)
                    currentOrientation = PORTRAIT_FLIPPED;
                else if(degrees>=135&&degrees<=225)
                    currentOrientation = LANDSCAPE_LEFT;
                else if(degrees>=315||degrees<=45)
                    currentOrientation = LANDSCAPE_RIGHT;

                if(currentOrientation == previousOrientation)
                    return;

                accEventExtra.oldOrientation = previousOrientation;
                accEventExtra.newOrientation = currentOrientation;
                accEventExtra.directionOfChange = determineDirectionOfChange(previousOrientation,currentOrientation);

                previousOrientation = currentOrientation;

                dispatchEvent(accEventExtra);
            }
        }
        private function determineDirectionOfChange(oldOrientation:String, newOrientation:String):String
        {
            var turned:String;
            switch(oldOrientation)
            {
                case PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                    switch(newOrientation)
                    {
                        case LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                            turned = TURNED_LEFT;
                            break;
                        case LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                            turned = TURNED_RIGHT;
                            break;
                        case PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                            turned = FLIPPED;
                            break;
                    }
                break;
                case LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                    switch(newOrientation)
                    {
                        case PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                            turned = TURNED_RIGHT;
                            break;
                        case LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                            turned = FLIPPED;
                            break;
                        case PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                            turned = TURNED_LEFT;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                    switch(newOrientation)
                    {
                        case LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                            turned = FLIPPED;
                            break;
                        case PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                            turned = TURNED_LEFT;
                            break;
                        case PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                            turned = TURNED_RIGHT;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                    switch(newOrientation)
                    {
                        case LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                            turned = TURNED_RIGHT;
                            break;
                        case LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                            turned = TURNED_LEFT;
                            break;
                        case PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                            turned = FLIPPED;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            return turned;
        }
    }
}

internal class SingletonEnforcer {public function SingletonEnforcer(){}}
```

[AccBasedOrientationEvent.as]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * Added a property to store the current linearRotation pre-computed so
     * each handler doesn't have to compute it.
     */
    public class AccBasedOrientationEvent extends Event
    {
        public var oldOrientation:String;
        public var newOrientation:String;
        public var directionOfChange:String;
        public function AccBasedOrientationEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false, oldOrientation:String=null, newOrientation:String=null, directionOfChange:String=null)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this.oldOrientation = oldOrientation;
            this.newOrientation = newOrientation;
            this.directionOfChange = directionOfChange;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage should end up looking something like this:

```
                   {
                   ...
                   var accManager:AccelerometerManager = AccelerometerManager.getIntance();
                accManager.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, handleAccelerometerChange);

                var locRot:Number;
                switch(accManager.currentOrientation)
                {
                    case AccelerometerManager.PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                        locRot = 0;
                        break;
                    case AccelerometerManager.PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                        locRot = Math.PI;
                        break;
                    case AccelerometerManager.LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                        locRot = Math.PI/2;
                        break;
                    case AccelerometerManager.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                        locRot = -Math.PI/2;
                        break;
                }

                var ge:GenericActuator = Actuate.tween(this, 1, {rotateAroundCenter:locRot});
                            ...
                        }

private function handleAccelerometerChange(event:AccBasedOrientationEvent):void
        {
            var locRot:Number;
            switch(event.newOrientation)
            {
                case AccelerometerManager.PORTRAIT_DEFAULT:
                    locRot = 0;
                    break;
                case AccelerometerManager.PORTRAIT_FLIPPED:
                    locRot = Math.PI;
                    break;
                case AccelerometerManager.LANDSCAPE_LEFT:
                    locRot = Math.PI/2;
                    break;
                case AccelerometerManager.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT:
                    locRot = -Math.PI/2;
                    break;
            }

            var ge:GenericActuator = Actuate.tween(this, 1, {rotateAroundCenter:locRot});
            //rotateAroundCenter = event.linearRotation;
        }
```

Note: I'm using the Actuate library in the example to animate the rotations, this isn't at all necessary, everything else here should be built in or supplied above.

Comment: nice idea what you do by using Accelerometer , i tried some solution for my code and it is worked , not professional code but now its do the work , simply the solution is  add timer in : private function changeOrientation(evt:StageOrientationEvent):void , for one second then set the width and other property ,, i will try your code , thanks for the brilliant idea .

Comment: thanks, yah sounds like your issue must be related somehow to the timing of the event being dispatched vs the time those properties for fullScreenWidth and height get updated (perhaps you could listen for a resize event instead).  Let me know if you end up using this and run into any difficulties so far it's worked out without issues for me.